# Spark microframework 2.1 deploys well in Tomcat but not version 2.5

Tags: gradle

I am not good at all this web stuff, but I have managed to port a small Spark-tinyweb application to serve REST services from jetty to Tomcat, following the project from Leonan Luppi in

https://github.com/leonanluppi/SparkTomcat

But in the folder WebContent/WEB-INF/lib, if I replace the file

**spark-core-2.1.jar**

to a newer version:

**spark-core-2.5.jar**

The application does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your `build.gradle` file specifies the dependency on `com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.1`. You have to upgrade the version in the file too so that Gradle can resolve the dependencies and compile your app.